# How to get the remote/peer IP address from an SSL/ssl_st structure in C?

Tags: c, openssl, ip-address, frida

The things I have previously tried are getting the socket fd from `SSL_get_wfd` and then passing it to `getpeername`. I also looked the the BIO object/functions but without any luck. Attempted to look at the openSSL implementation in `/usr/include/openssl` but then again with no luck.

Does anyone know how to get the remote IP address (and port) to which an openSSL socket is connected?

Some context:

```
socket fd: 64 // the file descriptor doesn't look incorrect (to me)
after getaddress, socklen: 28 // the length of the plausible address also looks correct
sockaddr ptr: 0x7b0b0fcac0, val: 0x0 // the pointer is empty despite being allocated :(
```

edit: the documentation I based my work on:
https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/openssl/1.0.1c/structssl__st.html

Comment: What you describe should work and does for me. Do you have the addrlen argument set correctly on input to getpeername? (Note as for all C libraries, headers including those in /usr/include contain only declarations not implementations.)

Comment: I do allocate addrlen correctly and it is set to the correct length after getpeername which makes me believe it is called correctly. One fact I did not mention is that I'm hooking this function with Frida (passing js variables to NativeFunctions).
Anyways, I was able to get the host name by using SSL_get_servername.

Comment: If addrlen is (wrongly) set to zero before getpeername(), addrlen will be set to the length of the address ('correct') but the address will NOT be stored in addr; see the man page (or POSIX). SSL_get_servername _on client_ is the name _specified_ in SNI as the _desired_ server, which is not always the host you actually connect to, and _can_ be omitted entirely (although on the _public web_ nowadays many servers reject a handshake without SNI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frida has nice features related to [Socket](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#socket)s.

```js
        var address = Socket.peerAddress(fd);
        // Assert address not null
        console.log(fd, address.ip + ':' + address.port);
```

View Sockets activity;

```js
Process
  .getModuleByName({ linux: 'libc.so', darwin: 'libSystem.B.dylib', windows: 'ws2_32.dll' }[Process.platform])
  .enumerateExports().filter(ex => ex.type === 'function' && ['connect', 'recv', 'send', 'read', 'write'].some(prefix => ex.name.indexOf(prefix) === 0))
  .forEach(ex => {
    Interceptor.attach(ex.address, {
      onEnter: function (args) {
        var fd = args[0].toInt32();
        if (Socket.type(fd) !== 'tcp')
          return;
        var address = Socket.peerAddress(fd);
        if (address === null)
          return;
        console.log(fd, ex.name, address.ip + ':' + address.port);
      }
    })
  })
```

Output example

```
$ frida -Uf com.example.app -l script.js --no-pause
[Android Model-X::com.example.app]-> 
117 write 5.0.2.1:5242
117 read 5.0.2.1:5242
135 write 5.0.2.1:4244
135 read 5.0.2.1:4244
135 read 5.0.2.1:4244
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old and the "huihoo" link is dead. But this this does come up when searching as it did for me.

I tested and indeed *SSL_get_wfd()* and/or *SSL_get_rfd()* do return socket descriptor. In my case either returned the same socket index.

At least for using a sockets based BIO and of course you must already be connected, accepted, etc., to already have a socket created for the SSL context.

This would be your first step to verify what you are getting from one or both of these functions. If failed they would return a -1 (not a valid descriptor).

Assuming you got an socket like I do, then it becomes more of a sockets question (less an OpenSSL one). You can use *getpeername()* of the socket to get a "struct sockaddr", which  in turn use that to call *getnameinfo()* which will give you a hostname or numeric string representation of the IP address.